# Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, wamp, wampserver

I'm developing CakePHP based application, on WAMP.

For some reason I cannot run cake bake anymore.

After I run command:

c:\Program Files\wamp\www\my-application>"c:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-246
0\app\Console\cake.bat" bake

... I'm getting following error:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.6 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : my-application
Path: c:\Program Files\wamp\www\my-application\
---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake Model
Path: c:\Program Files\wamp\www\my-application\Model\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
#0 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php(1
05): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#1 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTas
k.php(927): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
#2 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTas
k.php(864): ModelTask->getAllTables(NULL)
#3 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTas
k.php(954): ModelTask->listAll(NULL)
#4 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTas
k.php(203): ModelTask->getName()
#5 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTas
k.php(91): ModelTask->_interactive()
#6 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php(437): Model
Task->execute()
#7 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php(434): Shell
->runCommand('execute', Array)
#8 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(2
07): Shell->runCommand('model', Array)
#9 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(6
6): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#10 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\app\Console\cake.php(36): ShellDispat
cher::run(Array)
#11 {main}

c:\Program Files\wamp\www\my-application>
```

It worked before. I think that problem started after PHP was upgraded.

I followed lot's of instructions like:

[CakePHP Bake Shell Error: Database connection “Mysql” is missing, or could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952880/cakephp-bake-shell-error-database-connection-mysql-is-missing-or-could-not-b)

[CakePHP Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280245/cakephp-database-connection-mysql-is-missing-or-could-not-be-created)

[CakePHP bake Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688472/cakephp-bake-error-database-connection-mysql-is-missing-or-could-not-be-crea)

... etc, but did not solved my problem.

I have to mention that my CakePHP application WORKS, and that only problem I have is that I cannot run any of cake bake options.

Comment: go to c:\Program Files\wamp\www\my-application\app and then run cake bake

Comment: But I do not have app directory...

Comment: ok. where ever you app is located you need to go to path and app directory (../app). and then run cake bake. e.g. app>cake bake

Comment: Run `Console/cake -app c:\path\to\your\app\directory bake`.

Comment: @bancer still the same :-(

Comment: Make sure you have pdo_mysql loaded for php cli.

Comment: `#10 C:\Program Files\wamp\www\cakephp-2460\app\Console\cake.php(36): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)` - why cake.php file is in `app` folder? I think it should be in `lib` directory, isn't it?

Comment: @bancer That file is supposed to be there. [https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Console/](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Console/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add a path to the mysql socket file

In app/Config/Database.php add the unix_socket parameter

'unix_socket' => '/path/to/sql/socket'

Comment: maybe, but where is socket files in Wamp structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I also experienced on my windows server OS and fixed by a simple step given below.

1. open active php.ini and enable `extension=php_openssl.dll` by un-commenting that line.
2. restart the IIS/ web server

It should work now.

An additional step:

3. backup the content of the TMP folder and then delete files from within the folders from TMP folder.